# HTML/CSS Positioning makeing a nav bar float bottom right

Tags: html, css

<strike>I'm trying to get my navbar to float bottom right within a container</strike>

The navbar positions bottom right now, however it does not position within the container (.wrapper) code, so question now is, how can i make it position properly within the wrapper?

Site-head code in style.css:

```
.site-head {position: relative; display: table; width: 100%; padding-top: 50px; background: #203041 no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;}
```

The container code in style.css:

```
.wrapper { width: 100%; max-width: 1240px; margin: 0 auto; }
```

The nav-bar code in style.css:

```
a {color: #FFFFFF; text-decoration: none; font-weight: bold; }
a:hover {color: #cc3727;}
header {background: #fff; width: 100%; height: 180px; position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 100; background: #203041 no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;}
nav {poistion: absolute; right: 0; bottom: 0; float: right;}
#menu-icon {display: hidden; width: 40px; height: 40px; background: #4C8FEC url(images/menu-icon.png) center;} 
a:hover#menu-icon { background-color: #444; border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;}  
ul { list-style: none; padding: 0; } 
li {display: block;float: left;padding: 10px; font-family: 'Proxima Nova Light', 'Open Sans', sans-serif; color: #FFFFFF;}
.active {color: #cc3727;}
```

HTML used:

```
    <header class="site-head">
    <div class="cf wrapper">
    <div class="logo">
      <span class="site-logo">Logo</span>
    </div>
    <nav>
        <a href="#" id="menu-icon"></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li>|</li>
            <li><a href="#" class="active">Music</a></li>
            <li>|</li>
            <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
            <li>|</li>                
            <li><a href="#">Social</a></li>
            <li>|</li>                
            <li><a href="#">Bio</a></li>             
        </ul>
    </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

I have browsed a few stackoverflow threads without luck. I am fairly new to making websites.

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ua9hq72g/

Edit: @Amit solved the issue via proofreading.

Edit edit: The navbar positions bottom right now, however it does not position within the container (.wrapper) code, so question now is, how can i make it position properly within the wrapper?

Answer (score 2):

Using correct spelling helps. JSFiddle hints you when you're wrong, but you need to be ***tidy***, and pay attention to red syntax highlight.

**poistion != position**

```
nav {position: absolute; right: 0; bottom: 0; float: right;}
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ua9hq72g/1/)

Comment: Thank you, it now positions bottom right, however it does not seem to do this within the container, (.wrapper), any idea how to fix this?

Comment: That depends on what EXACTLY you're trying to achieve. There are several things that are interfering with this (particularly, `position: absolute`)

Comment: I created a screenshot here: http://i.gyazo.com/228990f88a3ae0d564873eb9dfa8ad5b.png as you can see the navbar positions outside the outlined wrapper, im trying to make it so the Bio part is within the "box"

Comment: What I was trying to say is that there is more than 1 way (probably more than 5) to change your current structure to achieve that, and the "correct one" depends on several factors, such as responsiveness. Start by removing absolute positioning, play with your CSS, when you're "close" to what you need, post that as a new question (unless of course you manage to do that alone)